# Create a table with ListView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a kind of a table with ListView component. I am able to show the data in the listView with this code

```
constructor() { super(); const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
     dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
      }; 
    }

  render() {
    const appData = this.props.appData;
    return (
      <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> {I18n.t('appDetail.moreInformations')} </Text>
      </View>
      <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>} />
      </View>
      )
    }
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      marginTop: 10,
    },
    title:{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    list:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:'space-around',
        paddingTop: 10
    }

  });
```

However I didn't found a solution to put each item on the left of its cell. And also to set the max items per row to two. My final result should looks like this table(without border obviously)

```
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item 1.                      | item 2.                     |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item 3.                      | item 4                      |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| item5                        | item 6                      |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Do you have an idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FlatList and set to it the `numColumns={2}` prop and `style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}`. In my case I'm working with 3 cols: FlatList with `numColumns={3}`:

```
 <FlatList
    style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}             //<-- This Line
    numColumns={3}                                  //<-- And this one
    data={this.props.myList}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.Id}
    renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
/>
```

[Image: FlatList whit numColumns={3}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnzA8.png)